# apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=139

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I install apache2 on ubuntu 18.04. This is fresh install with all default configuration.

I tried to start apache2 but failed. And this is what I see.

```
# systemctl status apache2.service 
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-03-11 23:17:35 WIB; 13s ago
  Process: 9151 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=139)

Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id apachectl[9151]: Segmentation fault
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id apachectl[9151]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id apachectl[9151]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=139
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 11 23:17:35 xdn.id systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

When I check /var/log/apache2/error.log, there is empty.

What's wrong with this error?

Comment: Try `sudo apachectl configtest` to figure out the problem with apache configuration

Comment: got the same error when I tried to switch to php7.3, used `sudo a2enmod php7.3` but did not run `sudo a2dismod php5.6`

Comment: @PavelAlazankin You're right! We've to disable older version of PHP first and then enable latest. In my case it was 7.4 after I update to 8.2

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The "status=139" error must have something to do with having multiple, conflicting versions of PHP enabled.

I am running 18.04 and an old PHP site I run only locally ceased to work.  I am guessing aptitude installed and enabled php7.2, possibly when I installed kubuntu-desktop a few weeks back.

Regardless, I had two versions of PHP enabled:

```
 $ cd /etc/apache2/
 $ l mods-*/php*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Mar  2  2017 mods-available/php7.0.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Oct  1  2018 mods-available/php7.0.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Jul  1  2017 mods-enabled/php5.6.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.6.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Jul  1  2017 mods-enabled/php5.6.load -> ../mods-available/php5.6.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 May 28 06:05 mods-enabled/php7.2.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.2.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 May 28 06:05 mods-enabled/php7.2.load -> ../mods-available/php7.2.load
```

In my case, *I am fine with using php5.6, because the site is not online* and is purely for my local use only.  So disabling 7.2 did the trick:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

Now my php mods-enabled are less confusing to apache3:

```
 $ l mods-*/php*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Mar  2  2017 mods-available/php7.0.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Oct  1  2018 mods-available/php7.0.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Jul  1  2017 mods-enabled/php5.6.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.6.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 Jul  1  2017 mods-enabled/php5.6.load -> ../mods-available/php5.6.load
```

Naturally **for a live site one would want to disable php-5.6 and leave the php7.2 enabled**, because you should run the newer version in real life.

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

Then the php mods should look like this:

```
 $ l mods-*/php*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jun  9  2017 mods-available/php5.6.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 867 Mar  2  2017 mods-available/php7.0.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Oct  1  2018 mods-available/php7.0.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Jul  7  2017 mods-available/php7.1.load
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 855 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Feb  8  2019 mods-available/php7.2.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 May 29 17:43 mods-enabled/php7.2.conf -> ../mods-available/php7.2.conf                                                                         
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  29 May 29 17:43 mods-enabled/php7.2.load -> ../mods-available/php7.2.load
```

Don't forget to resatart the server!

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Thanks to Pavel's comment for inspiring this line of research!

Comment: Thx for the solution, finally I got this fixed with multiple mods conflicts

Comment: Thank you! In my case i had enabled both php7 and php7.2 which can be misleading.

Comment: This solution helps me. I spent an hour why Apache couldn't start or restart when I tried to change PHP version from 7.3 to 5.6. And when I list all enabled PHP modules I found out there are two versions of PHP: 5.6 and 7.4, I deleted 7.4 files and Apache started successfully.  I found out that I have to change to PHP 7.3 first from 7.4 before change it to 5.6.

Comment: Thanks! This is one thing to remember, deactivate an old version before activating a new one. Indeed, we can suppose it's done automatically by the `a2enmod` command, but it isn't.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error and I fixed it by enabling PHP version 8.0 (current stable) and disabling PHP version 7.4 (old) in my ubuntu 20.04 by these commands:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.4
sudo a2enmod php8.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

After doing these check your apache status by:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

It has to be `green` and must show you `active (running)`.

> NOTE: You can do this to any PHP version that you have and want to
> change.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my case. I've installed multiple PHP version in Ubuntu 22.04. Even after I type `sudo a2dismod php5.6` and then `sudo a2dismod php7.2`, apache2 service can't started. The problem is my php7.0 mod is enabled. I don't know why it's enabled. So, in case you still get apache2 service not started, try to **disable** all apache2-mod-php to **every php version** you've installed. Then enable version that you want to use.

I don't know why I can't find the mod directory with the command given by Tom.

> Now my php mods-enabled are less confusing to apache3:
>
> `$ l mods-*/php*`

It says:

```
ls: cannot access 'mods-*/php*': No such file or directory
```

But, since my LAMPP stack run without problem, I don't care about "mod directories" at least for now